# Angular Nested ng-repeat. Compare Two Lists. Display if found / not found

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I currently have two lists which are being compared. One displays a list of colors and the other is a list of names that have chosen a specific color. This is simple to display. An example fiddle can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/37dq96tj/

```
<div ng-repeat="eachColor in colors">

    {{eachColor.name}} Selected By: ->

    <span ng-repeat="eachName in names" ng-if="eachName.catid == eachColor.id">
          {{eachName.name}}
    </span>
</div>
```

The problem I am facing which I thought would be easy to do, would be to display the word "none" if no name is listed for that color. I thought I could do it this way which works if only one name is in the 2nd list. See: https://jsfiddle.net/37dq96tj/2

```
{{eachColor.name}} Selected By: ->

<span ng-repeat="eachName in names">
    <span ng-if="eachName.catid == eachColor.id">{{eachName.name}}</span>
    <span ng-if="eachName.catid != eachColor.id">NONE</span>
</span>
```

But if I add another name, this will not work. I'll end up getting duplicates "NONE" values. See: https://jsfiddle.net/37dq96tj/4

This seems simple, but I haven't figured it out. Hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Also, another question I'd definitely like to know is using nested ng-repeats this way is the ideal way to display this type of data?

Thanks!
T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `ng-if` can use a filter on the array that will match the id's.

The filter lets you create an alias for this filtered array which you can then check for length to show "none"

```
  <span ng-repeat="eachName in names | filter: {'catid': eachColor.id} as filteredNames">
      {{eachName.name}}
    </span>
    <span ng-if="!filteredNames.length">None</span>
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/37dq96tj/7/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this

```
<div ng-app="appX" ng-controller="appCtrl">
  <h5>COLORS</h5>
  <div ng-repeat="eachColor in colors">

    {{eachColor.name}} Selected By: ->
    <span ng-repeat="name in colorSelectedByUsers(eachColor)">{{ name }}</span>

  </div>

</div>
```

I have created a function `colorSelectedByUsers(color)` that returns array of users or array with single string of "None"

```
var app = angular.module("appX", []);
app.controller("appCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.colors = [{
    "id": 0,
    "name": "Red"
  }, {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Blue"
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Green"
  }];

  $scope.names = [{
    "id": 0,
    "catid": 2,
    "name": "Jim"
  },
  { "id": 1,
    "catid": 1,
    "name": "Frank"
  }]

  $scope.colorSelectedByUsers = function(color){
    var users = [];
    for(var u in $scope.names){
        if($scope.names[u].catid == color.id){
        users.push($scope.names[u].name);
      }
    }

    if(users.length == 0){
        users.push("None");
    }

    return users;

  }
});
```